# sorting and printing scores from high to low

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

i need to write a code for a bowling game that will take names and scores from the user, and stop when the user hits enter without writing a name or score. Then take that info and get and print the average of the scores and print the scores and names from the highest to the lowest. This is what i have so far but i can't figure out the sorting code and how to print without a bunch of 0's if the user didn't fill in the array all the way (10 max in this case).

this is a different class to get the average, highest and lowest scores:

```
class BowlingScore
{

    public int LowScore(int[] scores, int j)
    {
        int min = scores.Where((v, i) => i < j).Min();
        return Array.IndexOf(scores, min);
    }

    public int HighScore(int[] scores)
    {
        int max = scores.Max();
        return Array.IndexOf(scores, max);
    }

    public double AverageScore(int[] numbers, int j)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            sum += numbers[i];
        }
        return (double)sum / j;
    }
    public void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {

        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

}
```

}

```
        and this is the main: static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BowlingScore bs = new BowlingScore();
        const int MAX = 300;
        const int SIZE = 10;
        int i;

        // create an array with 10 elements
        string[] scoreInfo = new string[SIZE];
        string[] names = new string[SIZE];
        int[] scores = new int[SIZE];



        Console.WriteLine("Saturday Coder's Bpwling Team");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter in  a name and a score for each person on the team,");
        Console.WriteLine("For example, ''Mary 143''. Just hit Enter when you are done");

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter in a name and a score:  ");


            // Read one line of data from the file and save it in inputStr
            string inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
            // if statement to break when the user enters a zero
            if (inputStr == String.Empty)
            {
                break;
            }
            // The Split method creates an array of two strings
            scoreInfo = inputStr.Split();
            // Parse each element of the array into the correct data type
            names[i] = scoreInfo[0];
            scores[i] = int.Parse(scoreInfo[1]);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("The avarage score for this game was {0:N}.", bs.AverageScore(scores, i));
        int temp = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < scores.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (scores[j] > scores[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = scores[j + 1];
                    scores[j + 1] = scores[j];
                    scores[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            Console.Write($"{scores[i]}\n");




    // sort the array in ascending order
    // print out lots of messages so we can see the sort work

    Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey(true);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Keep a counter of number of entered values. Use that for printout loop limit instead of scores.length.

Comment: How do keep a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        List<int> scores = new List<int>();
        scores.Add(int.Parse(-your-string-input-)); //Add value to List
        scores.Min(); //Min Value
        scores.Max(); //Max Value
        scores.Average(); //Average
        scores.Sort(); //Sort the score List
        scores.Reverse(); //Reverse if necessary
        scores.Clear(); //Clear the score list
```

C# really spoils you with all this utilities, i suggest you go learn some [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) though, its good for you as a programmer